# ¿Cómo pasar el state con Redux a página?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Estoy empezando con Redux y estoy algo atascado en pasar el state desde un componente a otro. Quiero pasar el nombre del proyecto del state a la página de crear nueva keyword, pero no me aparece el nombre. ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Esta es la página donde quiero que aparezca el {props.projects.name}. Me está cogiendo el payload correcto por id, pero no logro que aparezca en el h2. He probado a hacer un map al projects y si me sale, pero el funcionamiento de la aplicación al hacer un map no es el esperado pues en el sidebar también muestro los proyectos.

````
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { newKeyword, validateForm, obtainDomains } from '../actions';
import Layout from '../components/dashboard/Layout';

const NewKeyword = props => {

    // Obtenemos el id que estamos recibiendo por url
    const { id } = props.match.params;

    useEffect(() => {
        props.obtainDomains(id);
    }, []);
    
    // State para la keyword
    const [ keyword, setKeyword ] = useState({
        name: ''
    });

    const { name } = keyword;

    const onChangeKeyword = e => {
        setKeyword({
            ...keyword,
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    const onSubmitKeyword = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Validar la keyword
        if (name === '') {
            props.validateForm();
            return;
        }
        // Agregar el state
        keyword.project_id = id;
        props.newKeyword(keyword);

        // Reiniciar el form
        setKeyword({
            name: ''
        })

    }
    
    return ( 
        <div className="NewKeyword">
            <Layout>
                <div className="titulo">
 
                <h2>Añadir nueva keyword de {props.projects.name}</h2>
                    
                </div>
                { props.errorform ? 
                <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    Todos los campos son obligatorios
                </div> 
                : null}
                <form onSubmit={onSubmitKeyword}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input 
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Keyword:"
                            name="name"
                            value={name}
                            onChange={onChangeKeyword}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Añadir</button>
                </form>
            </Layout>
        </div>
     );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        errorform: state.errorform,
        projects: state.projects   
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    newKeyword,
    validateForm,
    obtainDomains
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewKeyword);
```

El reducer

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'OBTAIN_DOMAINS':
            return {
                ...state,
                projects: state.projects.filter(item => item.id === Number(action.payload))
            }
        case 'NEW_DOMAIN':
            return {
                ...state,
                projects: [...state.projects, action.payload],
                errorform: false
            }
        case 'DELETE_DOMAIN':
            return {
                ...state,
                projects: state.projects.filter(item => item.id !== Number(action.payload)),
                domain: []
            }
        case 'VALIDATE_FORM':
            return {
                ...state,
                errorform: true
            }
        case 'CURRENT_DOMAIN':
            return {
                ...state,
                domain: state.keywords.filter(item => item.project_id === Number(action.payload))
            }
        case 'DOMAIN_DETAILS':
            return {
                ...state,
                domain: state.projects.find(item => item.id === Number(action.payload))
            }
        case 'NEW_KEYWORD':
            return {
                ...state,
                domain: [...state.domain, action.payload],
                errorform: false
            }
        case 'DELETE_KEYWORD':
            return {
                ...state,
                domain: state.domain.filter(item => item.id !== Number(action.payload))
            }
        case 'KEYWORD_DETAILS':
            return {
                ...state,
                domain: state.keywords.find(item => item.id === Number(action.payload))
            }
        case 'DELETE_KEYWORD_DETAILS':
            return {
                ...state,
                domain: state.keywords.filter(item => item.id !== Number(action.payload)),
                domain: []
            }
        case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case 'LOGOUT_REQUEST':
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case 'REGISTER_REQUEST':
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

¡Gracias!
````

Comment: Buenas, si dentro del componente printeas los props enteros, en ese objeto te muestra lo que buscas? Cuando pones algun valor dinámico y react no muestra nada es que da undefined o null probablemente, seguro que projects es un objeto y no una lista de elementos?

Comment: Probaste usando [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) para acceder al store de redux?